# EF6: Erro ao Gravar

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho o seguinte cenário que estou com problema:

Categoria:

```
public class Categoria
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

Produto:

```
public class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public string Detalhes { get; set; }

    public double Preco { get; set; }

    public bool Disponivel { get; set; }

    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
}
```

Configurações com Fluent Api:

```
public class CategoriaConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Categoria>
{
    public CategoriaConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Categoria");

        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.Descricao).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);

        HasMany(x => x.Produtos);
    }
}


public class ProdutoConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Produto>
{
    public ProdutoConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Produto");

        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.Descricao).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);

        Property(x => x.Detalhes).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);

        Property(x => x.Preco).IsRequired();

        HasMany(x => x.Clientes);

        HasRequired(x => x.Categoria);
    }
}
```

Método para adicionar o produto (onde está gerando o erro):

```
public void Adicionar(Produto produto)
{
    _db.Entry(produto.Categoria).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    _db.Set<Produto>().Add(produto);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

A forma como o objeto está sendo passado para o método Adicionar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha Action:

```
public ActionResult Create(ProdutoViewModel produto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var produtoDomain = MapearParaDomainModel(produto);
        produtoDomain.Categoria = _categoriaApp.ObterPorId(produto.CategoriaId);
        _produtoApp.Adicionar(produtoDomain);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Mensagem do erro:

> ```
> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
> ```

Como estou adicionando o produto não tem necessidade de buscar a categoria para colocar no objeto para depois gravar, então retirei a linha "produtoDomain.Categoria = ..." da action e retirei também a linha "_db.Entry(produto.Categoria)..." do método de gravação, o erro continua porém não é especificado o tipo dele.

Answer (score 1):

Você terá de fazer o `EntityState.Unchanged` para cada instância de Categoria que estiver na coleção de Produtos.

Por exemplo:

```
public void Adicionar(Produto produto)
{

    foreach(var cat in produto.Categoria)
       _db.Entry(cat).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    _db.Set<Produto>().Add(produto);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Ou,

```
public void Adicionar(Produto produto)
{
    /* Ele busca todas as categorias que estão mapeadas no contexto do banco */
    foreach(var catLocal in _db.Categoria.Local)
    {
       /*Apenas uma garantia que será alterado o status das categorias apenas do produto que está sendo trabhado.*/
       if(catlocal.ProdutoId.Equals(produto.ProdutoId)
           _db.Entry(catLocal).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
    _db.Set<Produto>().Add(produto);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Ou, como está marcando seus objetos de Categoria como inalterados, você usar o `_db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false` caso mantenha as categorias em um outro repositório ou método, e assim ele não carrega as categorias junto com o produto quando vier do banco de dados.

Ficaria assim:

```
public class ProdutoRepositorio
{
    ContextoBanco _db;

    public ProdutoRepositorio()
    {

        _db = new ContextoBanco();
        /* Instrução ao entity para que não carregue seus agregados*/
        _db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public void Adicionar(Produto produto)
    {
        /* Assim você não terá os objetos de categoria vinculados ao produto podendo fazer a lógica para manter a(s) categorias em um outro momento. */
        /*
        foreach(var cat in produto.Categoria)
           _db.Entry(cat).State = EntityState.Unchanged;*/

        _db.Set<Produto>().Add(produto);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu Jhon! Você falou que tem que fazer o "Unchanged" para cada Categoria da instância Produto, mas o produto só tem uma categoria.
Também desabilitei o Lazy Loading mas não deu certo também (Acho que ele não influência na gravação só na busca dos dados, certo?).

Comment: Se estiver salvando só o produto não precisaria também de marcar a categoria como inalterado.

Comment: O LazyLoading funciona também para manter um registro, caso você busque no banco para saber se é para atualizar ou adicionar... ele não vai carregar os objetos agregados e não vai ter que user o "Unchanged" para cada instância carregada.

Comment: Outra verificação que podemos fazer é, antes de salvar (aplicar o SaveChanges) é olhar os objetos que estão mapeados no Entity para alteração no banco de dados. Seria em _db.Produto.Local (com o debug da para navegar nesses níveis e verificar se existe apenas aquela entidade). Caso tenha mais de um objeto mapeado para a mesma instância da aplicação, recomendo utilizar o AsNoTraking nas consultas.

Desculpe na demora do retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Eu costumo utilizar a seguinte ideia na hora de persistir informacao no banco usando EF:

```
    public void AdicionarOuAtualizar(T entidade)
    {
        if (entidade.Id == default(int))
        {
            _contexto.Entry(entidade).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            _contexto.Entry(entidade).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

E na hora de criar a entidade Produto voce pode setar o CategoriaId = idCategoria sem buscar o objeto caso nao seja necessario.

A primeira vez que li sua pergunta achei que o motivo era exatamente o objeto categoria, ele poderia estar sendo buscado em um contexto e adicionado a referencia em outro contexto, no seu caso, _produtoApp e _categoriaApp nao foram criados com o mesmo context. Mas como seu erro persistiu removendo essa informacao, creio que nao seja o caso.